# Alternatives to numpy for efficiently applying a condition to an array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm doing one of the Google Foobar challenges and have come up with a solution using a numpy array that can churn through the maximum list of 2000 integers and find 40,888 "lucky triples" in about 1 second but I've just discovered the Foobar shell doesn't support numpy!

Could someone give me a steer on where I can read up on how to implement this without using numpy? I think it's vectorization I need to look into but I've drawn blank in what I've read so far.

I don't want to give away the solution but the specific code I'm looking to rewrite without numpy is below:

```
for potZ in l[l % potY == 0]:
    if potY != potZ:
        triples += 1
```

I've seen suggestions elsewhere that I should look into directed graphs but, given I'm so close to what I think (hope) is a workable solution, I did want to see it through - I've had a look at the source code of Numpy on Github but haven't found the relevant place yet.

Comment: Depends on what l is. Assuming it's a 1-dim numpy array. Then the solution could look like this: `[element for element in l if element % potY == 0]`.

Comment: Sorry yes, l is a list of integers. I've already tried a list comprehension in place of the numpy subsetting and it can get through the above 2000 integers in 3 seconds, so it's not as fast as numpy unfortunately

Comment: Python has lists, `numpy` has arrays (technically `ndarray`).

Comment: I don't think that you should add numpy tag when asking for non-numpy solution

Comment: I defer to the opinions of those who know better and can take the numpy tag out. I included it in case someone knew how numpy works under the hood and might be able to help me recreate a small aspect of its functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause time should be optimized, the python built-in function `filter` can help replacing the numpy function. Try something like this:

```
for potZ in filter(lambda x: x % potY == 0, l):
    pass
```

It's faster than list comprehension.